# How to prove limit of $2$ variables?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that the following limit exists, and is $1$, but I don't know how to prove it. I know of the definition of a limit "If $0 < (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} < \delta$ Then $f-L < \epsilon$" but I am finding it difficult to grasp that concept to a point where I can put it to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^{x^2+y^2}-1}{x^2+y^2}
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let $r = x^2+y^2$. Now prove that $r \to 0^+ \iff (x,y) \to 0$. Now conclude that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\exp(x^2+y^2) - 1}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \dfrac{\exp(r) -1}r$$
The limit on the right hand side is a well-known limit.

Comment: Thank you so much! To all of you that are posting answers, I didn't expect an answer so fast. I really appreciate all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with one variable limits, let $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$.  You will want to evaluate 
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{e^{r^2}-1}{r^2}.$$